# Heroku Redis development with nodejs

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-redis

I'm developing react app  and ım using nodejs for backend. I deployed project on heroku and ı used heroku-redis. Now ı want to develop some features. How can ı work on local ? When ı tried, ı couldn't watch changing and also when ı working on local, heroku server crashed. I didnt push anything but server crashed. I just want to change some codes and push again.

Comment: Are you running your app on local machine using `heroku web local` ?

Comment: yes. I can work on local with heroku. but when ı working on local, heroku server crashed. But ı didnt push anything.